Is this question a fit for this site?
I have an issue I am currently struggling to understand and unsure if it is an engineering question, physics question or if it's just an opinion based question and not a fit for any Stack Exchange site.
I have a handheld product that has a TMR sensor that is tripped by a magnet when it gets within a certain distance and shuts the device off. A MEMS accelerometer is also on this device to sense orientation to flip an LCD.
So, I have a case where sometimes the device isn't shutting off when the magnet gets to its "home" position. Yet when the device is flipped to a different orientation, the TMR sensor will switch and shut the device off. It has me completely baffled and unsure if asking for possible reasons is a fit for this site. What would you say?

see extended answer

This is a site for electronics design and while we do answer questions on electronic equipment pertaining to electrical engineering and circuit design, we answer questions that are oriented towards design.
That being said we would need something more in the question such as a schematic or design not just pictures to answer the question.

Thanks for the answer. As I mentioned in a comment, if I was to make a main site question, it would contain much more information. I can provide datasheets for the parts involved but not a huge amount in the way of schematics as this is work sensitive. This is, however my circuit design so it isn't just a product I picked up and am wondering what is happening. I re-read my question and saw that part wasn't clear

He is building something from components so it doesn't just seem to be "about equipment". I'm very interested in what he is doing and what is going wrong. Without enough details it MAY be that he is using an advanced new sensor type and is running foul of tyhe earth's magnetic field. It may be nothing like that. || A magnetic sensor that doesn't work if you look at it funny sounds like something I want to know about. || I've been wondering of I can sensibly (as opposed to just actually :-) ) make my own battery current monitors using Hall cells * - these MAY be another solution.


Interest only. In an every mV counts environment a magnetic sensor to measure current flow can be an excellent choice. These are available commercially at higher A ratings. I want something that works in the mA to 100's of mA range and costs about zilch.


I think that that is a wholly acceptable question, and I imagine that the large majority would agree with me.
Sometimes I imagine wrongly :-).
But / And:
Having more detail than you have provided above would be very useful.
Using the term "Tunneling magnetoresistance and providing an explanatory link like eg this one

PLUS a link to the datasheet
AND the magnet datasheet (or FULL description) would all help. .

You mention home position and different orientation without explanation or reference to eg ,

distance from magnet to sensor,
how much the over-field is compared to the worst case sensor specs,

You don't mention sensitivity,

absolute

or wrt
earth's magnetic field, or other possible magnetic fields,

any shielding,

electric current or powered inductors etc.


Some of these may be significant by their absence, but saying so would be useful.
Otherwise people will indeed be guessing in many cases.

My only drawback would be if it would just be a bunch of people guessing at the answer maybe?

Thank you for the extended. I was planning on adding all the relevant information if making a main site question. But I didn't think it necessary for a general overview and a "is this ok" type question. I need to do a couple more tests to eliminate things until I am a bit more clueless than I am now then I can think about doing a main site post
